# I want to use Eclipse while the company I am working in uses WSAD 5.1

Tags: eclipse, wsad5.1

Folks, I have just joined a company where they are using WSAD 5.1 which is painfully slow. Their rationale for using it is taht the final deployment will be on Websphere server.
I am used to Eclipse Europa and similar with JBoss as my app server.
Is there a way that I can use Eclipse with Websphere app server?

Comment: I'll only post this as a comment because I forget how it was set up, but I worked at a company that had a WebSphere plugin for Eclipse. Googling found this result: http://qjpro.sourceforge.net/eclipse.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I got something similar off Google - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0604_sun/0604_sun.html
There is a Websphere Community Server, which may be close to their actual server. I will post my answer as I get any closer.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that shares very much in common with the real WAS product. It's Geronimo with Tomcat and some extras. I suspect it may be an attempt by IBM to still keep the Websphere brand in the mind of those using the free product (and hopefully upsell them at some point). Still, if you can tell your employer you're using IBM-branded products (even though it's Geronimo/Tomcat/Derby/...), that may go some way to assuaging their concerns about not using WSAD :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, guess what? You work for them, they don't work for you :-)

You have two options that I can see.

1/ Go through all the rigmarole of trying to change their mind and letting you develop on baseline Eclipse (which may not be *that* difficult if you focus your arguments on, and quantify the benefits to be had); or

2/ Just set up and support your own installation of Eclipse/JBoss for development and introduce an extra local step testing with WSAD/WAS before pushing your code to the repository.

If you hide (2) well enough, they need never know. But check your corporate policies first, they may not allow unapproved software on *their* machines.

The thing is, if you have a good boss, they may allow this regardless if it means your productivity is higher.

The problem you have is that IBM's products (WSAD, RAD, RSA et al) all have very good integration, and possibly some subtle vendor lock-in ("advanced features"), with WAS which is harder to set up with the baseline Eclipse. That's something you'll have to figure out and maintain.

Your employers will be unlikely to help with that, or even condone it since, in their eyes, they have a solution: use WSAD. You need to convince them that the cost of doing it your way is outweighed by the benefits.

Comment: I bet you are a manager, and if not, you certainly have the potential ;)

Comment: I _was_ a manager (so I understand their mindset) but I was so unhappy doing it that my employer let me go back to being a tech. They'd rather have a happy productive tech than a somewhat psychotic manager who keeps a "kill list" (list of people to whack if I ever discover I have a terminal disease) taped to his monitor :-)

Comment: hey that sounds like my story ;) being back in the techie seat, i am trying to cleanup the environment a little. to add to the misery, i am in a java team which is soon migrating to .net, so i have been allocated the seat closest to the exit door. hence, any creativity i do has to be economical :) great thanks for your suggestions though. i will perhaps take point 0 above - shut up and comply with the employer ;)